# How to confirm if all points lie on sine wave.

Tags: signal-processing

Given at least 3 points $(x_{i}, y_{i})$, how to confirm if all points lie on a sine wave? Or alternatively, how to determine the parameters of a sine wave that best fits the data (I'm guessing amplitude and phase would be sufficient?).

Context: I am processing images and attempting to identify sinusoidal features within a rock face programmatically. I'm able to identify these as well as other features using edge detection. I'm now trying to isolate the sinusoidal features. I have a number of ideas of how to do this, the above idea would likely be the least computationally intensive but I've no idea hoe to go about it.

Comment: Welcome to Maths StackExchange. Please provide more context for your problem or include what you have tried so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

**Three points given**

Here is a program for three points given on line3 solved by least squares method.
Output signal tallies exactly with (goes through) the 3 given points.

Recently I was helped for  this by Bill on Mathematica site.

[image]

EDIT !:

Another signal containing 3 input points with exact match:

$$(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)=(1., 0.4, 3., 1., 12., -2.); $$
$$(a,b,c)= (2.1450555574383996,-1.9070717143143807,2.094645060163228);  $$
[image]

**More than three points given**

Note that if we give more than 3 points, a least square fit would be obtained in terms of the three coefficients using the same code.

Comment: Many thanks, will give this a go and report back

Answer (score -3):

The $3$ points if be ...

1. (a, b)
2. (c, d)
3. (e, f)
   then ...
   $\sin a = b$ and $\sin c = d$ and $\sin e = f$   then the $3$ points are on a sine curve.

However, I haven't come across anyone/anything that clearly states the *minimum* number of points for a sine wave. For instance if you know a relationship is *linear* (a straight line), you need only find $2$ points. From what I know, a sine wave has to be *periodic/cyclical* and has to have a *maximum* and a *minimum* and a *midline*, the max & min *equidistant* from the midline.

Comment: No matter how many points you have, so long as they have different $x$ coordinates, there are infinitely many sine waves that pass through all of them. This is known as *aliasing*. If you have an upper bound on frequency, then at least for equally spaced points there's the Nyquist theorem, which says something about how many points suffice to completely determine a sine wave, if the sine wave has a frequency less than the Nyquist frequency (which comes from the point spacing).

Comment: @KyleMiller, interesting. I'm familiar with basic sinusoidal modeling (temperature, etc.). I suppose it's a matter of eyeballing it from perioidicity in the data. Most inatances I've seen have been ones that inferred a sinusoidal pattern from *max* & *min* and *period* and sometimes (*cogito*) the *midline*. Gracias muchas.

Comment: @KyleMiller I'm not so sure this is true. Aliasing usually refers to duplication of spectrum components at multiples of the sampling frequency, I don't think it can be used to show that for a collection of points there exists a single sinusoid passing through all of them. For instance, if our points aren't equally spaced we don't even have such a sampling frequency to speak of, much less if the distances aren't rational multiples. I think $\{(1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(\pi,0)\}$ is an example of a set of points without any common sinusoid, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: @Tom Thanks, that's certainly an oversight — it should be that there are either zero or infinity solutions I believe. I don't mean to say that aliasing accounts for the existence of a solution, but rather that aliasing is the principle that there is not just a single sine wave that passes through some given points (these various sine waves are "aliases" of one another).